# How much data and computation power do I need to train a machine translation model using Transformer architecture?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, transformer, machine-translation, cloud-computing

I am working right now on creating a dataset to use in creating a machine translation model to translate between two dialects. I have two questions that I am trying to find an answer for:

1. How much data is enough? how many pairs of sentences would be sufficient to have a decent translation model that can prove the concept?
2. How much computation power would I need if I am going to use the transformer architecture? Would GPUs on Google colab be sufficient?